# Slim Framework Base URL

Tags: php, slim

I'm new to Slim Framework. How to get the base URL like with the Codeigniter function `base_url()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to set the base url manually FIRST before you can get it
as in this:

```
$app->hook('slim.before', function () use ($app) {
    $app->view()->appendData(array('baseUrl' => '/base/url/here'));
});
```

http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/49-how-to-deal-with-base-path-and-different-routes

Comment: I think he was asking how to "get" not "set"

Comment: yes I noticed, but you need to set first. it is not by default, edited my answer to clarify this

Comment: @SosialLab Right, to get [after setting using the above method]... in your templates, use something like this `<base href="{{ baseUrl }}" />`

Comment: Hi thanks for response. I use $app->render(). How to configure it?

Comment: @SosialLab You need to read the docs and learn how setting, getting, MVC structure, and slim coding work.

Answer (score 14):

With Slim v3, as it implements PSR7, you can get a PSR7 Uri object and call the getBasePath() method that Slim3 adds on it. Simply write:

```
$basePath = $request->getUri()->getBasePath();
```

From [Slim v3 documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html#the-request-method) :

> **Base Path**
>
> If your Slim application's front-controller lives in a physical subdirectory beneath your document root directory, you can fetch the HTTP request's physical base path (relative to the document root) with the Uri object's getBasePath() method. This will be an empty string if the Slim application is installed in the document root's top-most directory.

Be aware that the getBasePath() method is added by the framework and is not part of [PSR7 UriInterface](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/#35-psrhttpmessageuriinterface).

Comment: there is no such method `getBasePath()` in the PSR-7 Uri interface.

Comment: @StefanoTorresi : Maybe you misunderstood what I badly expressed (english is not my mother tongue): Slim3 offers a getBasePath() over the PSR7 Uri object. I never wrote this method is part of PSR7 Uri interface. Please refer to Slim3 docs.

Comment: I understood what you meant, but yes, as you admit yourself it's expressed incorrectly: the `getBasePath()` method is specific of `Slim\Http\Uri`, it is not PSR-7 compliant.
Given that the rest of the documentation suggests, and rightfully so, to hint against PSR-7 interfaces, using the implementation specific method will result in a vendor lock-in and will compromise the portability that PSR-7 support was meant to give in the first place.
To clarify your answer, I would suggest to drop the PSR-7 reference, because as it is now it implies that the suggested method is part of the standard.

Comment: much better! 

Comment: Sorry for being late to the party but I think currently the right method is   `getBaseUrl()`

Answer (score 6):

In a recent app where we're using Twig, we assign the httpBasePath as follows:

```
$view = $app->view()->getEnvironment();
$view->addGlobal('httpBasePath', $app->request->getScriptName());
```

The `addGlobal()` method is probably equivalent to `$app->view()->appendData()`, I'm not sure.

The advantage of using `$app->request->getScriptName()` is that we don't have to manually set a folder name or care what it is – one developer can have the repo located at `http://example.localhost` and another can have it at `http://localhost/projects/slim` and no configuration is required.

Answer (score 4):

Try this in index.php to set the base url for the view

```
$app->hook('slim.before', function () use ($app) {
    $posIndex = strpos( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/index.php');
    $baseUrl = substr( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, $posIndex);
    $app->view()->appendData(array('baseUrl' => $baseUrl ));
});
```

Comment: This reminds me of the same function in WordPress, this should be included in the "basics" of the framework documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I can get the base url with `{{ app.request.getRootUri }}` (I'm using Twig template engine).
Incidentally, this is the same as the 'SCRIPT_NAME' environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using TWIG then in Slim v3 call -

```
{{ base_url() }}
```

or use `{{ path_for('yourRouteName') }}`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the base url is to append the request url and the request root url like below:
`$req = $app->request;
$base_url = $req->getUrl()."".$req->getRootUri()."/";`