# Adding a base url path to slim router

Tags: php, slim

I have a bunch of routes and they all start with `/api/2.01`.

How can I add it once so it applies to all routes.  [Slim Framework Base URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481210/slim-framework-base-url) asks the same question, but I believe provides an outdated answer.

PS.  If instead of asking a new question, should I have instead somehow tagged the post which I believe is dated to be reviewed or something?

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->post('/api/2.01/books', function () {
    //Create books
});
$app->get('/api/2.01/books', function () {
    //getbook
});
$app->get('/api/2.01/books/{id}', function () {
    //Get book
});
$app->delete('/api/2.01/books/{id}', function () {
    //Create book
});
```

Comment: What version of slim are you using?

Comment: @nerdlyist  I am using Version 3.4.

Comment: I know you accepted an answer but I am curious are you going to be creating a group then for every minor update and patch (assuming that is what the 2.x.x is) rather then just making the update in a v2 group. Seems like this will grow unnecessarily large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Slim v2.0, you can do somtehing like:

```
// API group
$app->group('/api', function () use ($app) {

// Library group
$app->group('/library', function () use ($app) {

    // Get book with ID
    $app->get('/books/:id', function ($id) {

    });

    // Update book with ID
    $app->put('/books/:id', function ($id) {

    });

    // Delete book with ID
    $app->delete('/books/:id', function ($id) {

    });

});
```

as specified in the docs: http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/groups/

Comment: Thanks Pipe.  The documentation seems to be a little disjointed.  I am using Slim v3.4.

Comment: Its similar... documentation for v3 can be found here http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-groups

Comment: Thanks!  I incorrectly assumed it would be set something like `$app = new \Slim\App(['base'=>'/api/library']);`