# why slim requires full directory path for loading external assets(js/css) file

Tags: twig, slim

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="/slim/app/views/animations/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/slim/app/views/animations/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/slim/app/views/animations/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    hello
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to specify full directory path for loading the js and css files
(jquery.min.js and bootstrp.min.js and bootstrap.min.css).Here i have
(/slim/app/views/animations/) as the directory which contain all the 
files. if currently i am in the views directory i should use the 
(animations/whatever the file name) but it is not working in these
way. but if i use the full directory path it all works fine. why these
is happening can anyone explain.

(slim) is my root directory where i installed slim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Relative paths is not how you typically work with Slim. Your assets (JavaScript/CSS/images, etc) should be referenced absolute from your views:

```
src="/assets/js/myapp.js"
```

Routed URLs do not map directly to file system based resources because templates should not be accessed by URL publically - they are only served by the controllers.

A common slim [file structure](https://github.com/jimfrenette/slim3-mvc) looks like this:

```
app/
public/index.php
templates/
  view.html
assets/
  images/
  js/
  css/
```

[Some](https://github.com/damianopetrungaro/slim-boilerplate) add the assets subfolders directly into the public folder. 
[Others](https://github.com/awurth/Slim) have those folders on the root level.

However, in general, public assets (e.g. CSS, JS, images) should be beneath the public document root (accessible to the public).

One thing that could be helpful if you do not like this behavior is to use Slim's [basePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481210/slim-framework-base-url) variable.

You should be able to set the base URL as a View variable in a `slim.before` callback in your `index.php` so that it is available to all routes like this:

```
$app->hook('slim.before', function () use ($app) {
    $app->view()->appendData(array('baseUrl' => '/base/url/here'));
});
```

or

```
$app->hook('slim.before', function () use ($app) {
    $posIndex = strpos( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/index.php');
    $baseUrl = substr( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, $posIndex);
    $app->view()->appendData(array('baseUrl' => $baseUrl ));
});
```

And then apply it to the references in your HTML tag of the base template file and that's it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ base_url() }}/css/style.css" />
```

Or use [Uri::getBaseUrl()](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Uri.php#L807-L820), e.g.

```
$basePath = $request->getUri()->getBasePath();
```

Comment: Why slim dont use relative path